# .htaccess remove URL path segments that are causing an Internal Server Error

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following `.htaccess` Rewrite below seems working fine if the URL is something like: `example.com/news/post-1`

```
RewriteRule ^/?news/([^/]+)/?$ article.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, if the URLs have more parameters, something like: `example.com/news/post-1/comment-page-1` (URLs from another version of the website) I will get a 500 Internal Server Error.

How I can make it redirect to the related post instead of 500 Internal Server Error?

Comment: What do the logs show? Is the cause because of `slug` value? Could swap `([^/]+)/?` to `(.*)` if you don't care what is after `news/`.

Comment: Your rule does not match that second URL format to begin with.

Comment: Exactly, CBroe the rule was only made to work with one parameter, so how I can make it redirect to the main post if old URLs have multiple parameters?

Comment: user3783243 logs only show a "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error" the (.*) definitely helps, at least is not showing a 500 anymore.

Comment: Well write a second rule, that matches on one more "pseudo folder" in the URL?

Comment: "Could swap `([^/]+)/?` to `(.*)` if you don't care what is after `news/`" - Although that will end up passing the _wrong_ value to the `slug` URL parameter (which would then need to be removed or 404 in the PHP script). You could change the last part of the regex to `([^/]+)(?:$|/)` - to simply discard the rest of the URL, but that will potentially cause duplicate content issues. You are better off _redirecting_ to discard the unwanted part of the URL-path. @user3783243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the URLs have more parameters, something like: `example.com/news/post-1/comment-page-1` (URLs from another version of the website) I will get a 500 Internal Server Error.

That 500 error is caused by *something else* in your `.htaccess` file since the directive you posted would not apply (as stated by @CBroe in comments).

So, the 500 error could potentially be resolved by fixing whatever directive is causing this.

Incidentally, these are "path segments", not "parameters". You might see them as parameters to your script, but that's not what they are in the URL being requested.

> How I can make it redirect to the related post instead of 500 Internal Server Error?

If you want to resolve this by redirecting `/news/<slug>/<anything>` to `/news/<slug>/` then you could do something like the following near the *top* of your `.htaccess` file, before the existing rewrites:

```
# Remove additional path segments from the URL-path
RewriteRule ^(news/[^/]+/). /$1 [R=302,L]
```

The dot on the regex matches a single character after the last slash, so must therefore contain an additional path segment (at least).

The `$1` backreference contains just the part of the URL-path you are interested in (ie. `/news/<slug>/`) and redirects to this.

Note that this is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect. Always test with 302s to avoid potential caching issues before changing to a 301 (permanent) redirect once you have confirmed it works as intended.

Comment: Thanks, that´s exactly what I was trying to do.